# References on encryption in enterprise settings

Tags: encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enterprise Encryption Considerations](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/enterprise-encryption-considerations)

I'm making a document on enterprise security. I'm looking for references and inspiration on the following topics:

1. Enterprise encryption best practices;
2. Encryption secure coding best practices;
3. A checklist for encryption.

Comment: You should likely break these three into separate questions.  The link @minopret linked would be a good place to start for item 3 and probably item 1 as well.